# How to tell my boss I am leaving for my former employer

Tags: resignation

I started my new job back in October as I was frustrated with my former employment as I was no where near a promotion in my department.

I left for my new job that was a little bit more salary but ultimately less because of no overtime, I don't mind my new job but it does bore me quite often as I have been doing warehousing for 11+ years and it's a slower and quieter atmosphere here.

All of a sudden my former boss calls me and I have been offered a new job as injection moulding team leader with a lot of benefits and a huge pay rise,

How can I explain to my boss that I'm leaving for my old company without them thinking its just for the money?

Comment: Are you sure that all / most of reasons that caused your frustration will be gone?

Comment: Why do you have to tell them where you are going?

Answer (score 5):

just fill in your resignation letter.

> Dear [person]
>
> I regret to inform you that I'm resigning from my position as [bla]. I
>   have received a better opportunity that I find impossible to resist.

done. If your boss asks for more information, you can tell him you received a job offer at a position you feel you're more suited to.

Comment: Personally, I would spell received correctly. :)

Comment: @Ghost GAH! my dyslexia always screws me over, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to tell your Boss anything, other than that you're quitting. In fact, it may *hurt* you if you say too much.

What can happen is someone from your soon-to-be-former company can decide to sabotage you if they know where you are going (or worse yet, who you will be working under). All it takes is a quick phone call:

> "Hey Manager Bob at Acme, I understand Gregg Paddock took at job at your company. Speaking strictly off the record, I think you should know that we were on the verge of firing him for sexual harassment."

And then your new offer disappears.

You avoid all that with a modified version of [@Migz](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/85422/4675)'s letter:

> Dear [person]
>
> I regret to inform you that I'm resigning from my position, effective [yyyy-mm-dd].
>
> Sincerely,
>
> [you]

- Don't mention where you're going to anyone - you can do that after you start working there
- Don't update your social media (FB, LinkedIn) with your new position until later
- Say nothing during your exit interview

Comment: Not sure if this is OP's true name, but you may want to edit it out from the quote, as reading this in a search engine's result summary might be confusing and cause OP exactly the kind of trouble you speak about :)